# Problem installing Black Magic driver in High Siera

Tags: permission, privacy

I am installing a driver for a Black Magic Studio Recorder. As the last step (I assume) in the installation script it tells me I need to "allow" it in Security & Privacy under the Privacy tab. The driver does not show up as a choice.

Based on something from a web site I opened terminal and executed

```
sudo diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u`
```

It seemed to be actively doing something for about a minute but did not change anything in the privacy tab. I saw something somewhere about booting in recovery mode but did not get the complete story.

Comment: See [this Tech Note](https://help.livestream.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002052308-Allow-Blackmagic-Devices-to-be-Recognized-on-Mac-Computers) about this exact procedure.

Comment: thanks - I was looking in the wrong place for the allow button.